# Proof $||A \underline x|| > 0 \Leftrightarrow \underline x \neq \underline 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If  $n \geq m, A \in M(n,m)$ and  $rg(A)=m$
Proof $||A \underline x|| > 0  \Leftrightarrow \underline x \neq \underline 0$


a)If $m \neq 0 \leftrightarrow A \neq 0_M$

Suppose that $\underline x = \underline 0 \Leftrightarrow ||A \cdot \underline 0||=||0||$

which is a contradiction to $||A \underline x|| > 0 $

 therefore  $||A \underline x|| > 0  \Leftrightarrow \underline x \neq \underline 0$


b)If $m \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow A \neq 0_M \Leftrightarrow A > 0$

per definition:
$||A|| > \frac{||A \underline x||}{|| \underline x||}$ and $ \forall \underline x \neq \underline 0$ 

 then  $||A \underline x|| > 0  \Leftrightarrow \underline x \neq \underline 0$


$\Box$

Is any of these ways a correct proof?

If not where are the mistakes or what can I improve?

Comment: Both arguments seem confused... try to make clear what you want to prove first... there are also some logical mistakes, you start with and "if" and after some symbols an "if and only if" appears...

Comment: Other unclear things: how can you say that "$\underline x=\underline 0\Leftrightarrow ||A\cdot \underline 0||=\underline 0$" ??? I do not see the correlation between the two things...
How can you say that $A\neq0\Leftrightarrow A>0$??? By $A>0$ you mean positive definite? Or is it a mistake? (maybe you mean $||A||>0$?)

Comment: I meant $||A\cdot \underline 0||= 0$.Yes, you are right I meant $||A||>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rigorous proof would be as follows:

a matrix $A\in M(n,m)$ has rank $m$ (i.e., maximal rank) if and only if it represents an injective homomorphism from a vector space of dimension $m$ to a vector space of dimension $n$. So, if you start with a non-zero vector $\underline x$, its image $A\underline x$ will remain different from zero, thus $||A\underline x||>0$. It is also clear that $A\underline 0=\underline 0$. \\\